# echo plugin results on pages

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, actions

I am trying to get a query to echo on the frontend of wordpress from a plugin but haven't had much success. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Below you will find the simple script I am using:

```
    function getPageIDs()
    {
       include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/stage/wp-config.php' );
        global $wpdb;

       $row = $wpdb->get_row( 'SELECT pages FROM schemalocalbusiness WHERE id = 1');


        $pageIDs = $row->pages;

        $pageIDsArray = explode(" ", $pageIDs);

        foreach ($pageIDsArray as $page)
        {

                echo $page;

        }


    }
add_action('wp_footer', 'getPageIDs', 1);
```

I have tried several different alteration of this script with no luck. Thank you for your help!

This is what the database query returns:
[image: this is what the database query returns]

Comment: You wouldn't need to include wp-config.php again. 
Is the function called at all (add an echo outside the `foreach`)? Does the SQL return something when you run it against the database manually? Does it return a non-empty value for `pages`? Did you check that the output really doesn't show up in the source and isn't just hidden by a CSS rule?

Comment: I have tried not including the wp-config.php within each function I use. However, each time my database queries are unsuccessful. And yes, the query to the database is correct. I also check the source code on the front end to make sure it isn't hidden. I even went as for as to do a simple example:  function execute()
    {
        if(is_page(6))
        {
            echo '<h1>SUCCESS</h1>';
        }
        echo 'test';
    } add_action('wp_footer', 'execute'); and still the same results.... NOTHING! lol Thank you for your advice @janh

Comment: In your minimal example, is "test" outputted at least? In what way are your DB queries unsuccessful if you don't include wp-config.php, do they not return anything, or are they failing completely because there's no DB connection available / $wpdb isn't defined? Does `schemalocalbusiness` exist in your WP database or are you switching databases on the fly?

Comment: No, "test" doesn't even work. Without putting in the wp-config.php it doesn't return anything. Everything works with the query. Just not the add_action to the footer of the frontend pages. And yes,  schemalocalbusiness does exist in the WP database. I simply cannot get the hook to work.... @janh

Comment: Sounds like the query & its output isn't your problem, but something much more basic. Is this some hybrid setup where WP is being included in another framework? Does your theme call `wp_footer()`? Is the document completed (no error / exit that stops processing before `wp_footer()` is executed)?

Comment: Well, I put the add action and the function at the top of the page to make sure but I still have the same results. I just tried switching themes and still no luck. I also put the function at the top of my functions page. Thanks @janh for looking into this. It has been very bothersome! lol If you would like, I could send you the project in a zip file to view?

Comment: I'd need the complete environment to actually simulate it, that's hard to do. Have you made sure that `wp_footer()` is executed in your theme's template file that is being used (check the classes on the body-tag to see which file is used)? Also write something after `wp_footer()` should've been called and check whether it shows up in your document source, it sounds like either `wp_footer()` is not called at all or an error is stopping execution before your action is executed.

Comment: I'm calling this from my functions.php page in the plugin directory? The same code I'm using works for my child-theme with the Divi builder. Thus, I thought it would work for the plugin environment.   How do if find out if an error is stop it?

Comment: Is the plugin handling the request all by itself, or is it using the template? Can you edit the question and add a minimal example of the plugin you're using? As for checking for errors: basically, does `</body>` show up in the document source?

Comment: The plugin is being designed to work apart from or with any theme. The body tags are still in the source code.  Yes I will edit...

Comment: That code looks like it's not included on every page (or you'd get that output everywhere), how is it loaded? Also, `getPageIDs()` is called once and then added as an action to `wp_footer`, do you see the output of the first call?

Comment: Yes, the getPageIDs(); renders: 2,4,6,8. But the only place it is displayed is on the plugin page.

Comment: Again, how is the plugin page loaded?

Comment: Check above I made another edit.

Comment: Oh, so it's only displayed in the admin? You can't use wp_footer within the backend, it's only executed in the frontend, use the `admin_footer` hook if you want to execute within the admin.

Comment: I don't want it to display on the admin side. I need to display on the frontend of the website.                                                                      
                 Plugin API/Action Reference/admin footer
The admin_footer action is triggered just after closing the <div id="wpfooter"> tag and right before admin_print_footer_scripts action call of the admin-footer.php page.

This hook is for admin only and can't be used to add anything on the front end.

Comment: According to your code, you are using `all_admin_notices` now to include the page that registers the `wp_footer` action. That won't be executed in the front end.

Comment: I tried using the add actions wp-footer outside of the all_admin_notices and no luck.... All the documentation states this is possible to do....

Answer (score 0):

Once I got the syntax correct, @janh was correct. wp_footer has to be called BEFORE all_admin_notices. I was trying to call in wp_footer from all_admin_notices. Simple but frustrating! Thank you @jahn for all of your help!